# Notation for tensor field contractions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensors

Given a covariant $p$-tensor field $T$ on a manifold $M$, what is a good notation for the contraction of $T$ with a vector field $X$? For differential forms we have the interior product $\iota_X\omega$. I have seen notation such as $T\cdot X$ or $T(X,\cdot)$ or $T(X)$. At the moment I'm leaning towards using $T(X)$ since it seems clearer and less bulky. Any suggestions?

Comment: In physics, we like to use indices with Einstein-convention (implicit summation over repeated indices). I.e something like $T^{ijk}X_i$. But some mathematicians seem to dislike mentioning coordinates.

Comment: Yes I would prefer a coordinate free notation.

Comment: Abstract indices *are* coordinate-free notation---the notation $T^{ijk} X_i$ tells you that $X$ is contracted against the first component of $T$, and this is a coordinate-free statement. In any case we might write this quantity without indices as $T(X, \,\cdot\, , \cdots , \,\cdot\,)$.

Comment: Note that, e.g., since $T$ is a $p$-tensor, the notation $T(X)$ requires additional explanation to indicate the slot of $T$ into which $X$ is contracted.